# code: "CLOUD_AGENT_FORBIDDEN" Dropbox download

Tags: dropbox

```
POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download
Error: You have reached your cloud agent usage limit
Network
Request Headers
authorization: Bearer sl.xxxxxxx
dropbox-api-arg: {"path": "/zip.csv"}
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 369
Host: content.dropboxapi.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
 
{code: "CLOUD_AGENT_FORBIDDEN"}
 
Dropbox download = undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```

i tried creating another dropbox account using another email id but still the same error..

Answer (score 0):

This error message doesn't appear to be coming from Dropbox, but rather from Postman itself.

It looks like you can find information on this error here: https://community.postman.com/t/you-have-reached-your-cloud-agent-usage-limit/24669

Comment: since I was using the postman from the cloud agent , finally figured that postman has limited the no of API calls from cloud agent.